# BAD_ACCESS while calling a timer's handle

Tags: nstimer, exc-bad-access, objective-c++

I have this realization of timer in Timer.h/.mm

```
@implementation Timer

static multiset<Timer *> timers;

- (void) run
{
    action();

    if (!repeat) 
    {
        timers.erase(timers.find(self));
    }
}

+ (void) run: (Action) action after: (int) seconds repeat: (bool) rep
{
    Timer * timer = [[Timer alloc] init];

    timer->action = action;
    timer->repeat = rep;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds
                                     target:timer
                                   selector:@selector(run)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:rep];

    // timers.insert(timer);       // ANY version will fail
    timers.insert([timer retain]);
}

@end
```

After that, I call it from my UIViewController.mm:

```
[Timer run:^ 
{ 
    // some code...
}
after:2];
```

But it falls with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when time come w/o entering [Timer run]!

```
#0  0x00000020 in ??
#1  0x000b87a5 in __NSFireTimer
#2  0x00dfafe3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
```

What am I doing wrong? Why it calls cs:20h? I have no such value (32) in my program at all!

After some minor changes timer tries to call

```
#0  0x04ae6000 in ??
```

instead of

```
#0  0x00000020 in ??
```

when the code seg is located beyond 0h(?) & ~15000h.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to [copy the block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW2) in `run:after:repeat:` because the one you pass it is stack based and gets destroyed when the scope it is in unwinds.